# IBM Case Manager Script Adapter and Widget?

Tags: ibm-content-navigator, ibm-case-manager

I am a newbie in IBM Case Manager and currently exploring case builder and case navigator. I am stuck with the Script Adaptor and widget parts of this. I googled it but unable to find anything that might be really helpful for me to start with Script Adaptor.
Can anyone help me to understand this or where can I get details about script adaptor and Wiring the Widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [this explanation of the script adapter widget and it's use-cases](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSCTJ4_5.2.0/com.ibm.casemgmt.help.doc/acmwrh120.htm) is what you're looking for. Basically a script-adapter allows you to execute javascript-code upon triggering by 'a wire'.

You'd want to use script-adapters for "small" manipulations or logic that can be done with only a few lines of javascript-code (for readability and maintainability purposes). As your scripts get larger you might want to consider transforming it to a widget.

A widget (typically) is a html/javascript component that can be placed anywhere on the page(just like the out of the box widgets). Unlike scriptadapters (that are to be 'build' on the page itself), a (custom)widget is to be compiled and installed before it can be used on a page. The easiest way is by using the Eclipse IDE with [this plugin](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/e8206aad-10e2-4c49-b00c-fee572815374/entry/Eclipse_Plug_in_for_Custom_Widget_Action_and_Custom_Editor_Development_in_IBM_Case_Manager?lang=en), alternatively here's a [DIY guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSCTJ4_5.3.0/com.ibm.casemgmt.development.doc/acmwt000.htm).

Comment: Thanks, Ivo Jonker. Your explanation about Script Adapter and Widgets was really helpful. I tried some of the predefined widgets and wiring them using Script Adaptor by referring the examples given in the IBM Redbook and the links you shared.

Comment: But, nothing that I found explains things well. I also found some video tutorials on YouTube and contents within IBM Redbook that explain the relevance of how to use Widgets, Wiring and Script Adaptor but doesn’t explain why exactly I need to do things the way they are given, the exact meaning and purpose of those terminologies, etc. Only trying the step could not clear my concepts. So now I am able to do things given in that reference material but will not be able to try something on my own.It would be really helpful if you could share something that could explain the meaning of terminology